# Store user's personal Excel column filters in a cookie-like file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I'm developing a reporting app (how exciting!) that puts out HTML, PDF, and Excel reports.  In the HTML version I let the user select which columns they care about, and filter out the others.  This is completely handled in the browser, so all the data & HTML generated and cached for xyz report is the same for Alice as for Bob, even though they display different columns in their browsers.  The columns they hide are saved in a cookie, so if they switch browsers, they have to reapply these settings.

I'd like to do the same thing for Excel files.  Is there any way I can save this list of columns to hide somewhere like Personal.xls or anywhere else, and include a Macro in the generated Excel file that reads the column list and applies it?

(Even better yet would be if the Macro could be stored in Personal.xls and automatically run when spreadsheets matching a certain regex were opened, but perhaps that's impossible, or maybe should be a separate question.)

Is anything like a cookie possible to implement in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

In the VBA macro you could use the File System Object to read and write to a file. An example of using this object from MSDN:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True)
a.WriteLine("This is a test.")
a.Close
```

You could use FSO to insure that the file is there, create it or open it, write to it, and read from it.

You could also store the columns in a separate workbook that would be generated and read from in VBA without the code overhead of FSO, but FSO seems like a cleaner option for what you are doing.